# Automated interaction term creation and testing in R

Tags: r

Happy to close this if it's off topic, but I was curious if anyone is aware of any feature selection packages in R that try different interaction combinations. For example, if I have 3 variables `[a,b,c]` it might test `a+ b + c + a:b`, `a+ b + c + a:c`, and `a+ b + c + b:c` as part of the model selection process. Thanks!

Comment: Interactions are `:` in R, not `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a little bit and here is my approach, perhaps it helps you:

```
values <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

combinations <- combn(x = 3, m = 2)

vapply(1:length(values), function(x){

  one <- values[combinations[1,x]]
  two <- values[combinations[2,x]]

  return(values["a"] + values["b"] + values["c"] + one*two)

}, FUN.VALUE = 1)
# [1]  8  9 12
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good approach, but it probably won't scale too easily no? I was hoping someone might know of a package already built to do exactly this.

Comment: You can pass a function to `combn()` too - `combn(letters[1:3], 2, FUN=paste, collapse=":")` for instance.